# Net beans 6.9 under 64 bit windows

Tags: java, netbeans, 64-bit

Will netbeans 6.9 (and whatever else I'll need for Java development - JVM, mysql, etc.) install under the 64 bit version of Windows 7 professional?  The netbeans website says (well, implies) it's untested. Need to know if I need to reinstall 32 bit Windows 7 before a Java class starting tomorrow. Thanks for any help.

Update:  went ahead under 64 bit and all is working fine.

Comment: Can you give info on the performance of NB under 64 bit windows? Do you also use a 64 bit JDK ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm running Netbeans 6.9, Java 6 (64 bit) and MySQL under Windows 7 Pro 64 bit. Netbeans I'm using with Java, Ruby, Python and C/C++ (with Cygwin). All work fine.